# Почему разные адреса одного и того же элемента динамического массива?

Tags: c++, функции, указатели, ссылки, динамические-массивы

Я создаю динамический массив и отправляю его в функцию, если потом сравнивать адреса элементов массива в главной и вызываемой функции они различаются (кроме 1 строки), почему так происходит? Они же должны ссылаться на один и тот же адрес в памяти.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void Go(char **mas, int N, int M)
{
    cout << "Адресация элементов в доп-ф:" << endl;
    for(short i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        for(short j = 0; j < M; ++j)
        {
            cout << mas[i][j] << " = " << &(&mas)[i][j] << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int M = 3;
    int N = 3;
    string text = "Hello_World!";

    char **mas = new char* [N]; //строки
    for(short i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        mas[i] = new char[M]; //столбцы
        for(short j = 0; j < M; ++j)
            mas[i][j] = text[i * M + j];
    }

    cout << "Адресация элементов в гл-ф:" << endl;
    for(short i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        for(short j = 0; j < M; ++j)
        {
            cout << mas[i][j] << " = " << &(&mas)[i][j] << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    Go(mas, N, M);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Вообще-то, что такое `&(&mas)[i][j]`? Есть переменная `mas`, который лежит где-то в памяти. Мы берем ее адрес, дважды разыменовываем, снова берем адрес... Словом, получаем что-то, что не имеет НИКАКОГО отношения к реальному массиву `mas`. Связанное с адресом местоположения `mas` в памяти - в первом случае как локальной переменной `main()`, во втором - аргумента `Go()`, находящегося, понятно, в другом месте...

Словом, если вам хочется получить адреса элементов массива (символов), то используйте просто

```
(void*)&mas[i][j]
```

Приводить к `void*` нужно потому, что иначе `cout` начнет исходя из типа выводить строки.

Answer (score 3):

> `&(&mas)[i][j]`

Поясню суть этой операции. Вы берёте адрес переменной `mas`, получается значение типа `(char***)`, обращаетесь к нему по смещению `i` и берёте оттуда указатель для следующей индексации. Когда `i`==0, вы попадаете на саму переменную `mas`, и далее в элементы `mas[j]`. Когда `i`>0, вы попадаете куда-то в соседнюю переменную, которая вообще другого типа и берёте оттуда какое-то значение за указатель. Поскольку дальше идёт снова `&`, вы не обращаетесь по этому указателю, а только увеличиваете его на `sizeof(char**)*j` и выводите его шестнадцатеричное значение.

Кстати у меня на linux выводятся одинаковые значения, но видно, что это не адреса, кроме первой тройки (похоже на соседние переменные M и N, а дальше M+4, M+8):

```
Адресация элементов в гл-ф:
H = 0x9ea5028
e = 0x9ea502c
l = 0x9ea5030

l = 0x3
o = 0x7
_ = 0xb

W = 0x3
o = 0x7
r = 0xb

Адресация элементов в доп-ф:
H = 0x9ea5028
e = 0x9ea502c
l = 0x9ea5030

l = 0x3
o = 0x7
_ = 0xb

W = 0x3
o = 0x7
r = 0xb
```

Если заменить это странное выражение на `(void*)&(mas)[i][j]`, в выводе получатся настоящие адреса элементов.

Comment: Спасибо, Ваш ответ помог. Возник небольшой вопрос:
Правильно ли я понимаю, если добавить эту строку в любую из функций
`cout << *mas[1] << " - " << &mas[1] << endl;`
она выводит первый элемент из 2-го массива указателей (2-ой строки) и адрес  указателя на элемент?

Comment: @АлександрГрабовский, `mas` - указатель на начало (адрес) массива указателей на строки. `mas[1]` - второй элемент массива указателей (адрес строки или, что то же самое, её первого символа), `*mas[1]` - первый символ массива символов, на который указывает второй указатель массива указателей, на начало которого указывает `mas`. `&mas[1]` - адрес второго элемента массива указателей (на строки), то же самое, что и `mas+1`.